# Possibility of segmentation fault with mutex in class with multithreading

Tags: c++, c++11, thread-safety, segmentation-fault, mutex

With multiple threads (`std::async`) sharing an instance of the following class through a `shared_ptr`, is it possible to get a segmentation fault in this part of the code? If my understanding of `std::mutex` is correct, `mutex.lock()` causes all other threads trying to call `mutex.lock()` to block until `mutex.unlock()` is called, thus access to the vector should happen purely sequentially. Am I missing something here? If not, is there a better way of designing such a class (maybe with a `std::atomic_flag`)?

```
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>
class Foo
{
   private:
      std::mutex mutex;
      std::vector<int> values;
   public:
      Foo();
      void add(const int);
      int get();
};
Foo::Foo() : mutex(), values() {}
void Foo::add(const int value)
{
   mutex.lock();
   values.push_back(value);
   mutex.unlock();
}
int Foo::get()
{
   mutex.lock();
   int value;
   if ( values.size() > 0 )
   {
      value = values.back();
      values.pop_back();
   }
   else
   {
      value = 0;
   }
   mutex.unlock();
   return value;
}
```

Disclaimer: The default value of 0 in `get()` is intended as it has a special meaning in the rest of the code.

Update: The above code is exactly as I use it, except for the typo push_Back of course.

Comment: where is the seg fault?

Comment: I don't see a problem with this class, but you should use `lock_guard<>` or `unique_lock<>` to acquire mutexes and automatically release when the RAII wrapper goes out of scope. Are you showing the entire class definition?

Comment: Also, what are you doing with objects of this class apart from accessing them concurrently? Are you copying them around?

Comment: Updated question. @AndyProwl: There is just one object of this class, shared_ptr is just for convenience in the early phase of development. @ hmjd: yep except for such typos, thanks

Comment: @stefan: Can you show the client code?

Comment: @AndyProwl what do you mean by "client code"? This is part of a larger project involving MPI, so not suited for copying to SO. I'm new to parallelization, thus I'm taking small steps and eliminating possible problems class by class. If this code is fine, I'm happy ;-)

Comment: @stefan: The code that uses your class (creates, accesses, modifies, etc.) I believe what's happening is that your object gets copied somehow. The operations of your class that we can see are perfectly protected by your mutex, so the only possible problem is with the operations we can't see. The compiler generates implicit copy constructor and copy assignment operators for your class, and those are not thread-safe. So if an assignment or copy construction happens in parallel with a modification through `add()`, you have a race condition.

Comment: @AndyProwl: Nope, no copying of this object done whatsoever. Segfault seems to be of different origin, but it's hard to get hold of it since it's not consistently happening and valgrind has way to much garbage output due to MPI. Thanks for pointing out the possible issue of copying the object, I've adjusted my code as David Schwartz suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than not using RAII to acquire the lock and using `size() > 0` instead of `!empty()`, the code looks fine. This is exactly how a mutex is meant to be used and this is the quintessential example of how and where you need a mutex.

As Andy Prowl pointed out, instances can't be copy constructed or copy assigned.

Comment: _That will cause a compile-time error should anyone abuse the interface._ It won't compile anyway, because having `std::mutex` as member prevents from generating default copy constructor and assignment operator.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the "improved" version:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>
class Foo {
   private:
      std::mutex mutex;
      typedef std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock;
      std::vector<int> values;
   public:
      Foo();
      void add(int);
      int get();
};
Foo::Foo() : mutex(), values() {}
void Foo::add(int value) {
   lock _(mutex);
   values.push_back(value);
}
int Foo::get() {
   lock _(mutex);
   int value = 0;
   if ( !values.empty() )
   {
      value = values.back();
      values.pop_back();
   }
   return value;
}
```

with RAII for acquiring the `mutex` etc.